# Can it be possible to determine Frames Per Second If i use CAEAGLLayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I am trying to figure out the Frames Per Second calculation.

In my Code:

```
 @interface myView : UIView
  {
  }
```

And, in .m file

```
    + (Class) layerClass
    {
        return [CAEAGLLAYER class];
    }
```

I tried using CADisplayLink:
LIke:

```
 @interface myView : UIView
  {
  }
  @property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *dLink;
```

and .m file

```
  1. dLink = [CADisplayLInk] ... selector (Mycallback:));
  2. adding currentRunLoop to dLink.
```

Problem:
 "MyCallback" is invoked 60 times per second, irrespective of the rendering speed. 
 What i understood from this is that, "MyCallback" is invoked at refresh rate of screen which has not related with current fps.

Question:

"What is the way to calculate the real fps that are happening in CAEAGLLayer".

NOTE: I am using this CAEAGLLayer [ UIView] in GStreamer.

Comment: What does the statement `render [CAEAGLLAYER class];` do?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. typo error. it is 'return'. :)Edited question.

Comment: I believe the frame rate is fixed at 60 FPS, and you've confirmed that yourself as your callback function is called every frame.

Comment: Are you want to set the frameInterval? Default fps is 60, while you can set frameInterval to 2, fps is 30.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What i want to get is for example: i have a callback that should be called on each time frame is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

To change FramePerSecond,

```
self.displayLink.frameInterval = 2;
```

While default value is 1, FramePerSecond = 60 / frameInterval.